# Get Link from Parent Anchor to Div

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick

How can I set div's onClick href to my parent anchor href value??

```
<a href="getThisLink.html" target="_parent">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    <span>
    <div onclick="parent.location.href='**Link me with my anchor parent**' + 'params1';" >
           <span>Words Words Words</span>
    </div>            
</span>
</a>
```

*Note*: *I'm using this with my slideshow.*

Comment: So lemme get this straight, your expected behavior is to be able to click that `div` in order to retrieve parent a's href value?

Comment: It is not legal to place a block element such as a `div` inside an `a`.

Comment: Currently, only the image has the link. When I hover with my span, it's not clickable, so I add div with onClick event. Though it is working, I want to clean my html script to just add those link programmatically to reduce redundancy of adding the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `updateHref()` below takes a `div` element and looks for it's parent's parent tag. And (**only**) if it is an anchor (`<a>`) tag:

- The **onclick of the `div`** will take the page to **the `<a>`'s href plus urlParams**.
- The `<a>` href will now take to its **old url plus urlParams**.

[**Demo link here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsr5t/12/). Code below:

```
function updateHref(divElement, urlParams) {
    var parentAnchor = divElement.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (parentAnchor.nodeName != "A") return;
    var url = parentAnchor.href + urlParams;
    divElement.onclick = function() {
        parent.location.href = url;
    }
    parentAnchor.href = url; // override parent anchor href URL
}
```

Usage:

```
// for a specific div
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
updateHref(myDiv, "search?p=param1");

// for all divs of the page (whose parent's parent is an anchor tag)
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    updateHref(divs[i], "search?p=param1");    
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, a better alternative would be to use one of HTML5's aria elements to get the link you wish to retrieve. So instead of using an anchor tag, you could simply replace it with a div as such <div aria-href="getThisLink.html"></div>

Comment: You wouldn't be able to add the 'params1' as the navigation of the parent anchor is triggered and the execution of the 'onclick' is not guaranteed to complete. You would have to cancel the event bubbling so the link does not navigate.  (Something like jQuery's e.preventDefault())

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Seems like a fair point. I'll add something to deal with that.

Comment: Under html 5 an `a` can contain block level elements, the only restriction, now, seems to be that they (still) can't contain interactive elements (such as `input`, other `a` elements and so forth).

Comment: @acdcjunior @RobertoHernandez Thanks to both of you, since this is not valid. I changed this `div` into a span. Now my problem is, when I hover my title (`span`) element, it seems that span don't have a link.

Comment: I can work that out, do you still want to? (About the invalid HTML, actually, you can have a  `div` inside an `a`. What you cant have is a `div` inside a `span`. -- But, still, it will work, its just not valid HTML, that is, if you test it with a validator, it will fail, just that. If you can make it a valid HTML is better, though.)

Comment: Can you help me with that? :)

Comment: Look, I think the span does have a link, the thing is that the `span` is not as "stretchy" as the `div`, look: http://jsfiddle.net/fsr5t/13/ The span is the gray part only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid, but, here is the working script:

```
<a href="getThisLink.html" target="_parent">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    <span>
        <div onclick="location.href = this.parentNode.parentNode.href + '#param1'; return false;">
            <span>Words Words Words</span>
        </div>
    </span>
</a>
```